# Filling NoData for raster layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have a data in shapefile format.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrz0w2djmfwjf19/AAB5ilHZwVQkDDa3CrwRW_Yoa?dl=0

I converted the data to a raster format using ArcGIS. I filled the noData value with 0 using ArcGIS Raster Calculator tool.

`Con(IsNull("InputRaster"),0,"InputRaster")`

The output layer looks like this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqvd3tqnlq4bxzd/OUTPUT.PNG?dl=0

I need the data to contain the value 0 for other parts of Poland marked in red, i.e. either adjustment to the Polish borders or enlargement of the default created square.

Below is a view of the situation described and an shapefile file with Polish borders

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yqruulkjx929kca/AAC5TW1foct2w-fCZHTNa2nDa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During first geoprocessing step (rasterizing) use Environment Settings -> Processing Extent and for Extent select your shapefile with borders (or set these values manually for Top, Bottom, Left and Right) . That should fill your raster with Null values up to desired rectangle. These Null values you'll convert to 0s in your next step.